# C stack frame tracing

Tags: c, linux, gcc, stack

I'm trying my hand at stack smashing to follow along with a security text I have.  The code is as below.  Now, I have a few questions that I can't reconcile by myself after a few hours of staring at this, and any explanations would be greatly appreciated:

- Per the System V x86_64 ABI (http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) the args are pushed onto the stack in reverse order, yet it seems that 6, 5, and 4 (c, b, and a) reside at 0x7fffffffdf40, 0x7fffffffdf44, and 0x7fffffffdf48, respectively.  Or am I viewing 
  this wrong and these are the actual values? The reason I'm confused is that stack grows downward in memory, however large_string is declared and initialized first yet appears to have a lower address than a, b, or c (0x7fffffffde40) if these are the actual memory locations.
- If the args for the call to function() are pushed on the stack around 0x7fffffffdf40 then shouldn't the return address also be pushed right about here?  I don't see anything adjacent to that 4, 5, or 6 that seems to be a return address, so I'm thinking these are the actual variable memory locations?
- Perhaps the following is not too far off?:  frame for main() is at 0x7fffffffdf40 and function() is at 0xfffffffde1c?

Code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>

  void function_1(char *str, int a, int b, int c){
    char buffer[16] = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
    //
    strcpy(buffer, str);
    //
  }

  void function(char *ls, int a, int b, int c){
    a -= 3;
    b -= 3;
    c -= 3;
    function_1(ls, a, b, c);
  }

  int main(){
    char large_string[256];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 255; i++)
      large_string[i] = 'A';
    int a = 4, b = 5, c = 6;
    function(large_string, a, b, c);
  }
```

Debugger trace information:

```
Breakpoint 1, function_1 (str=0x7fffffffde40 'A' <repeats 200 times>..., a=1, b=2, c=3) at test.c:7
7     strcpy(buffer, str);
(gdb) print main
$1 = {int ()} 0x4005ab <main>
(gdb) print function
$2 = {void (char *, int, int, int)} 0x400573 <function>
(gdb) print function_1
$3 = {void (char *, int, int, int)} 0x40052d <function_1>
(gdb) x /500xg 0x7fffffffdd00
0x7fffffffdd00: 0x00007fffffffdd80  0x000000006562b026
0x7fffffffdd10: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000001
0x7fffffffdd20: 0x00007ffff7ffe788  0x00007ffff7de4678
0x7fffffffdd30: 0x0000000000000000  0x00007fffffffdd70
0x7fffffffdd40: 0x00007ffff7ffa160  0x00007fffffffde80
0x7fffffffdd50: 0x00007ffff7ffa1d8  0x00007fffffffde70
0x7fffffffdd60: 0x0000000000000000  0x00007ffff7de3e9c
0x7fffffffdd70: 0x0000000000000000  0x00000000f63d4e2e
0x7fffffffdd80: 0x0000000000000001  0x0000000000000003
0x7fffffffdd90: 0x00007ffff7ff99c8  0x00007ffff7de4816
0x7fffffffdda0: 0x0000000000000000  0x00007fffffffdde0
0x7fffffffddb0: 0x00007ffff7a18d28  0x00007fffffffdef0
0x7fffffffddc0: 0x00007ffff7a251a8  0x0000000003d8f538
0x7fffffffddd0: 0x00007fffffffdee0  0x00000003f7ffeae8
0x7fffffffdde0: 0x0000000100000002  0x00007fffffffde40
0x7fffffffddf0: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffde00: 0x00007fffffffde30  0x00000000004005a9
0x7fffffffde10: 0x0000000100000000  0x0000000300000830
0x7fffffffde20: 0x0000000100000002  0x00007fffffffde40
0x7fffffffde30: 0x00007fffffffdf50  0x0000000000400606
0x7fffffffde40: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffde50: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffde60: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffde70: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffde80: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffde90: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffdea0: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffdeb0: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffdec0: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffded0: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffdee0: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffdef0: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffdf00: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffdf10: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffdf20: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffdf30: 0x4141414141414141  0x0041414141414141
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
0x7fffffffdf40: 0x0000000500000006  0x000000ff00000004
0x7fffffffdf50: 0x0000000000000000  0x00007ffff7a36ec5
0x7fffffffdf60: 0x0000000000000000  0x00007fffffffe038
0x7fffffffdf70: 0x0000000100000000  0x00000000004005ab
0x7fffffffdf80: 0x0000000000000000  0x9222f893ea203108
0x7fffffffdf90: 0x0000000000400440  0x00007fffffffe030
0x7fffffffdfa0: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
0x7fffffffdfb0: 0x6ddd076c54e03108  0x6ddd17d536da3108
0x7fffffffdfc0: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
0x7fffffffdfd0: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000400610
0x7fffffffdfe0: 0x00007fffffffe038  0x0000000000000001
0x7fffffffdff0: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
0x7fffffffe000: 0x0000000000400440  0x00007fffffffe030
0x7fffffffe010: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000400469
0x7fffffffe020: 0x00007fffffffe028  0x000000000000001c
0x7fffffffe030: 0x0000000000000001  0x00007fffffffe359
0x7fffffffe040: 0x0000000000000000  0x00007fffffffe384
0x7fffffffe050: 0x00007fffffffe38f  0x00007fffffffe3a1
0x7fffffffe060: 0x00007fffffffe3b4  0x00007fffffffe3ca
0x7fffffffe070: 0x00007fffffffe3e0  0x00007fffffffe3f6
0x7fffffffe080: 0x00007fffffffe406  0x00007fffffffe411
0x7fffffffe090: 0x00007fffffffe461  0x00007fffffffe49a
0x7fffffffe0a0: 0x00007fffffffe4a6  0x00007fffffffe9c7
0x7fffffffe0b0: 0x00007fffffffe9f6  0x00007fffffffea27
0x7fffffffe0c0: 0x00007fffffffea33  0x00007fffffffea5e
0x7fffffffe0d0: 0x00007fffffffea73  0x00007fffffffebcc
0x7fffffffe0e0: 0x00007fffffffebe1  0x00007fffffffebec
0x7fffffffe0f0: 0x00007fffffffebfd  0x00007fffffffec27
0x7fffffffe100: 0x00007fffffffec42  0x00007fffffffec56
0x7fffffffe110: 0x00007fffffffec60  0x00007fffffffec71
0x7fffffffe120: 0x00007fffffffec88  0x00007fffffffecbc
0x7fffffffe130: 0x00007fffffffecc8  0x00007fffffffecd1
0x7fffffffe140: 0x00007fffffffece5  0x00007fffffffeced
0x7fffffffe150: 0x00007fffffffecff  0x00007fffffffed0e
0x7fffffffe160: 0x00007fffffffed33  0x00007fffffffed51
0x7fffffffe170: 0x00007fffffffed6c  0x00007fffffffed7e
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q
Quit
```

Comment: Which ABI, what is your problem? See [ask].

Comment: It should also be said that you aren't NUL-terminating your `large_string`, which may very well lead to trouble in `strcpy` before you even get to using your smashed stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure where you got that arguments are pushed to the stack. Sure, some arguments are, but not in your case. Four arguments, all 64 bits or smaller, are passed in registers.

The arguments you are seeing on the stack are not the arguments passed to `function_1`. They are the arguments passed to `function`, stored on the stack so it can pass them on to `function_1`. I am assuming, based on evidence, that you are compiling without optimizations here, as otherwise you'd see no function calls at all.

I believe the rest of your misunderstandings can be resolved with that one immediately.